# Terminate Spring Boot application after a certain time

Tags: java

How can I terminate a running Spring Boot application after a certain time?

In other words, I will run my spring boot application today and I want to terminate two days from now:

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder().sources(Main.class).run(args);
```

Comment: [Schedule a task](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) to shutdown the application after a the specified time. What's the issue you're having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to gracefully shutdown spring boot application described in documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-exit

so basically to gracefully shutdown spring boot application you should just call

```
System.exit(SpringApplication
                .exit(SpringApplication.run(ExitCodeApplication.class, args)));
```

In order to schedule this, you can use spring boot scherduled task: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

All in all you will have some service which will have this method:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 2 * MILLIS_IN_DAY, initialDelay = 2 * MILLIS_IN_DAY)
public void shutdownApp() {
    System.exit(SpringApplication
                .exit(SpringApplication.run(ExitCodeApplication.class, args)));
}
```

And you enable this scheduled method you need to annotate your application class with `@EnableScheduling`