# How does springboot set the timeout exit?

Tags: spring-boot

Such as setting 1 minute no operation, the system will automatically exit.
This is my setup, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
server.session.timeout=60  


public class BigYouApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BigYouApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(BigYouApplication.class);
}
```

}

Comment: [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) `session.timeout` does not affect shutdown boot program

Comment: You should go throw the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203181/terminate-spring-boot-application-after-a-certain-time. It may help.